# How can I make an effective mocking suite on objects who constructors take no arguments?

Tags: java, junit, mocking, mockito

I have a card game I made a few years ago, and now I've learned about mocking with Mockito. So far, my card object looks like:

```
  public Card(){
    this.value = new CardValue(determineFace());  //assigns the output of a randomly chosen card to Card's this.value
                                                  //by plugging a call to determineFace() into a CardValue
    this.suit = determineSuit(); //this.suit is assigned a suit at random

  }
```

where determineFace() is:

```
  public static String determineFace(){ //determines a face at random so that CardValue in this.value's init has a parameter
    String f = null;

    int rand = (int)(Math.random()*13);

    if (rand == 0){
      f = "2";
    }
    if (rand == 1){
      f = "3";
    }
    if (rand == 2){
      f = "4";
    }
    if(rand == 3){
      f = "5";
    }
    if(rand == 4){
      f = "6";
    }
    if(rand == 5){
      f = "7";
    }
    if(rand == 6){
      f = "8";
    }
    if(rand == 7){
      f = "9";
    }
    if(rand == 8){
      f = "10";
    }
    if (rand == 9){
      f = "J";
    }
    if (rand == 10){
      f = "Q";
    }
    if (rand == 11){
      f = "K";
    }
    if(rand == 12){
      f = "A";
    }
    return f;

  }
```

suit is part of

```
public enum Suit{
    CLUBS, DIAMONDS, HEARTS, SPADES
  }
```

where a CardValue is a:

```
  protected String face; //a CardValue's verbal name
  protected int numeric; //a CardValue's numeric value 

  public CardValue(String faceVal){
    face = faceVal; // set's a CV's face name passed into the constructor
    numeric = findNumericVal(faceVal); //sets the numeric value equal to the output of the call to findNumericVal on the faceVal
  }
```

However, I'm really confused of how to go about mocking CardValue to Mockito so I can test Card's methods. I also want to test CardValue's methods. I'm a little unsure of whether to use @InjectMocks bc it seems like its always used with objects that don't have no args parameters. In trying to make mocks and test them with JUnit and Mockito, I've gotten errors about having thenReturn() being tried with the wrong type in those parens, I've gotten values that have shown up as null in my asserts. How can I make effective mocks of my objects?

Comment: Which piece of this are you trying to test?  One strategy would be to modify `determineFaces` to take the random number as a parameter and then make a second constructor for `Card` that has an `int` parameter.  Then you wouldn't need mocks at all.

Comment: I want to mock Card and CardValue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome onboard of Stackoverflow!

This is a solution without mocking because I don't see a reasons to use mocking.

All what you need is to substitute the random function by custom one in the tests.

The `Card` class has a static field `randomGenerator` which will be overwritten in the tests. BTW, I simplified the `determineFace()` to one line and removed the explicit constructor just to have more compact code.

```
class Card {
    static Supplier<Integer> randomGenerator = () -> (int) (Math.random() * 13);

    static String[] supportedFs =
            new String[]{"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "J", "Q", "K", "A"};

    final CardValue value = new CardValue(determineFace());
    final Suite suit = determineSuit();

    static String determineFace() {
        return supportedFs[randomGenerator.get()];
    }

    static Suite determineSuit() {
        // TODO: to be finished according to your logic.
        return Suite.CLUBS;
    }
}
```

This is an example of test class:

```
public class CardTest {
    @Test
    public void cardConstructionWhenRandomIsZero() {
        // Given custom random generator which returns always 0.
        Card.randomGenerator = () -> 0;

        // When
        Card actualCard = new Card();

        // Then
        Assert.assertEquals("2", actualCard.value.face);
        Assert.assertEquals(0, actualCard.value.numeric);
        Assert.assertEquals(Suite.CLUBS, actualCard.suit);
    }

    @Test
    public void cardConstructionWhenRandomIsOne() {
        // Given custom random generator which returns always 1.
        Card.randomGenerator = () -> 1;

        // When
        Card actualCard = new Card();

        // Then
        Assert.assertEquals("3", actualCard.value.face);
        Assert.assertEquals(0, actualCard.value.numeric);
        Assert.assertEquals(Suite.CLUBS, actualCard.suit);
    }
}
```

Sure things, you can use data providers to combine test cases for each possible random values.

One bad point of above solution is the real random generation will be not tested. For this case you can have a test with real random generation but match the actual value as part of supported values:

```
@Test
public void cardConstructionWithRealRandom() {
    // When
    Card actualCard = new Card();

    // Then
    Assert.assertThat(actualCard.value.face, Matchers.isIn(Card.supportedFs));
}
```

---

**UPDATE**: based on the comments.

If you still want to use `Mockito` you can emulate the behavior of the random generator by this way:

```
@Test
public void cardConstructionWhenRandomIsZero() {
    // Given custom random generator which returns always 0.
    Card.randomGenerator = Mockito.mock(Supplier.class);
    Mockito.when(Card.randomGenerator.get()).thenReturn(0);

    // When
    Card actualCard = new Card();

    // Then
    Assert.assertEquals("2", actualCard.value.face);
    Assert.assertEquals(0, actualCard.value.numeric);
    Assert.assertEquals(Suite.CLUBS, actualCard.suit);
}
```

---

**UPDATE 2**: based on the comments.

```
@Mock
Supplier<Integer> mockedRandomGenerator;

@Test
public void cardConstructionWhenRandomIsZero() {
    // Given custom random generator which returns always 0.
    Card.randomGenerator = mockedRandomGenerator;
    Mockito.when(mockedRandomGenerator.get()).thenReturn(0);

    // When
    Card actualCard = new Card();

    // Then
    Assert.assertEquals("2", actualCard.value.face);
    Assert.assertEquals(0, actualCard.value.numeric);
    Assert.assertEquals(Suite.CLUBS, actualCard.suit);
}
```

Comment: the reason to use mocking is because I need to learn it fast and I want ideally to do it with my own code

Comment: thanks! is there a way to do it with @Mock instead of using the mock(Class c) method?

Comment: now I'm getting an error that says: "randomGenerator cannot be resolved or is not a field"

Comment: Updated my post with `@Mock` usage. Make sure you defined the package visibility for your new field.

Comment: I shoulda also added the determineSuit() method:   public static Suit determineSuit(){
    
    int randNum = (int) (Math.random() * 4); //generates a random value [0,4) as ints, so there can only be 0, 1, 2, 3
    
    if (randNum == 0){
      return Suit.CLUBS;
    }
    else if (randNum == 1){
      return Suit.DIAMONDS;
    }
    else if (randNum == 2){
      return Suit.HEARTS;
    }
    else{ //this did not compile with an else-if at the end
      return Suit.SPADES;
    }
  }

Comment: Keep moving the same way, create new random generator for `Suit`, etc. Nothing special, everything is the same.